# python 3.6 decode dict bytes to json not working

Tags: python, json, utf-8

I have a data in the below bytes format,

```
{'command': 'MESSAGE', 'body': b'\x04\x08{\x0b:\tbody"n\x04\x08{\x08:\tdata{\n:\x0bstdout"\x14output-data\n:\rexitcodei\x00:\x0bstderr"\x00:\x0boutput0:\nerror0:\x0estatusmsg"\x07OK:\x0fstatuscodei\x00:\rsenderid"\x13server1:\thash"%903ff3bf7e9212105df23c92dd8f718a:\x10senderagent"\ntoktok:\x0cmsgtimel+\x07\xf6\xb9hZ:\x0erequestid"%7a358c34f8f9544sd2350c99953d0eec', 'rawHeaders': [('content-length', '264'), ('expires', '1516812860547'), ('destination', '/queue/test.queue'), ('priority', '4'), ('message-id', '12345678'), ('content-type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'), ('timestamp', '1516812790347')]}
```

and trying to decode and convert it as JSON formatted data but its not working. I tried with `data.decode()` and `data.decode('utf-8')` and tried `json.loads` as well but nothing working.

When I tried with `data.decode('utf-8')` got below error,

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 215: invalid start byte
```

and when I tried with `data.decode('ascii')` get below error,

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 215: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Am confused myself whether am doing right way or anything am missing with this data conversion and parsing.

**Update 1:**

Just now found that this data is generated using Ruby with PSK security plugin and this message object has `.decode!` `public_method`. So is there any way to use the same public_method in python to decode it or if possible using PSK also would be fine.

Comment: I would base64 encode the value before submitting it to `json`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Do you want me to try encode before perform `json.loads` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  As far as I can see this is not necessary.  We need to encode here not decode.

Comment: Your binary data most definitely isn't UTF-8 so there is no way to decode it using that codec.

Comment: @tripleee  Then why does `encode('ascii')` work?

Comment: It quite certainly doesn't: `'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'` and if you make it a string, then the `.encode('ascii')` will fail if the string contains something which isn't representable in ASCII, which is a 7-bit encoding (so any code point whose value is above 0x7F).

Answer (score 3):

JSON is a Unicode format, it cannot (easily and transparently) accommodate arbitrary byte strings. What you can easily do is save a blob in some textual format -- `base64` is a common choice.  But of course, all producers and consumers need to share an understanding of how to decode the blob, rather than just use it as text.

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec 26 2015, 18:08:53)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> d = {'json': True, 'data': b'\xff\xff\xff'}
>>> json.dumps(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ... yada yada yada ...
TypeError: b'\xff\xff\xff' is not JSON serializable
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(d['data'])
b'////'
>>> base64.b64encode(d['data']).decode('ascii')
'////'
>>> d['data_base64'] = base64.b64encode(d['data']).decode('ascii')
>>> del d['data']
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"json": true, "data_base64": "////"}'
```

I very specifically used a different name for the encoded field to avoid having any consumer think that the base64 blob is the actual value for the `data` member.

Random binary data most definitely isn't valid UTF-8 so obviously cannot be decoded using that codec.  UTF-8 is a very specific encoding for Unicode text which cannot really be used for data which isn't exactly that. You usually *encode,* rather than *decode,* binary data for transport, and need to have something at the other end decode it back into bytes.  Here, that encoding is base64, but anything which can transparently embed binary as text will do.

Comment: Another common option is to insidiously decode the binary data into Latin-1 or Windows code page 1252 and then be happy that the result you have *seems to be* Unicode. But now, it's easy for bugs to happen -- readers will assume that this is just Unicode text, and blow up in new and interesting ways, or just produce [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) like in the good old days.

Comment: This works! But my main problem is, need to parse from the body value which is in bytes.

Comment: This shows you *exactly* how to save bytes as JSON. My example is the `data` field instead of the `body` field but otherwise completely 1:1.

Comment: Another pattern for binary data, from Node.js, is `{"type":"Buffer","data":[4,8,123,11,58,9,98,111…]}`

Answer (score 1):

If that is your data and you are trying to round-trip it through the JSON serializable format, this will do it:

```
import json
import base64

data = {'command': 'MESSAGE',
        'body': b'\x04\x08{\x0b:\tbody"n\x04\x08{\x08:\tdata{\n:\x0bstdout"\x14output-data\n:\rexitcodei\x00:\x0bstderr"\x00:\x0boutput0:\nerror0:\x0estatusmsg"\x07OK:\x0fstatuscodei\x00:\rsenderid"\x13server1:\thash"%903ff3bf7e9212105df23c92dd8f718a:\x10senderagent"\ntoktok:\x0cmsgtimel+\x07\xf6\xb9hZ:\x0erequestid"%7a358c34f8f9544sd2350c99953d0eec',
        'rawHeaders': [('content-length', '264'), ('expires', '1516812860547'), ('destination', '/queue/test.queue'), ('priority', '4'), ('message-id', '12345678'), ('content-type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'), ('timestamp', '1516812790347')]}

# Make a copy of the original data and base64 for bytes content.
datat = data.copy()
datat['body'] = base64.encodebytes(datat['body']).decode('ascii')

# Now it serializes
jsondata = json.dumps(datat)
print(jsondata)

# Read it back and decode the base64 field back to its original bytes value
data2 = json.loads(jsondata)
data2['body'] = base64.decodebytes(data2['body'].encode('ascii'))

# For comparison, since the tuples in 'rawHeaders' are read back as lists by JSON,
# convert the list entries back to tuples.
data2['rawHeaders'] = [tuple(x) for x in data2['rawHeaders']]

# Did the data restore correctly?
print(data == data2)
```

Output:

```
{"command": "MESSAGE", "body": "BAh7CzoJYm9keSJuBAh7CDoJZGF0YXsKOgtzdGRvdXQiFG91dHB1dC1kYXRhCjoNZXhpdGNvZGVp\nADoLc3RkZXJyIgA6C291dHB1dDA6CmVycm9yMDoOc3RhdHVzbXNnIgdPSzoPc3RhdHVzY29kZWkA\nOg1zZW5kZXJpZCITc2VydmVyMToJaGFzaCIlOTAzZmYzYmY3ZTkyMTIxMDVkZjIzYzkyZGQ4Zjcx\nOGE6EHNlbmRlcmFnZW50Igp0b2t0b2s6DG1zZ3RpbWVsKwf2uWhaOg5yZXF1ZXN0aWQiJTdhMzU4\nYzM0ZjhmOTU0NHNkMjM1MGM5OTk1M2QwZWVj\n", "rawHeaders": [["content-length", "264"], ["expires", "1516812860547"], ["destination", "/queue/test.queue"], ["priority", "4"], ["message-id", "12345678"], ["content-type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"], ["timestamp", "1516812790347"]]}
True
```

Comment: I would recommend to use a separate member name like `'body_base64'` to avoid any chance of a consumer thinking that the encoded blob is the actual data.

Comment: @mark Tolonen Thanks! Yes that's how my data is and this data was generated using Ruby with PSK security plugin and just found that this message obj has `.decode!` `public_method`. So is there any way to use the same public_method in python to decode it or if possible using PSK also would be fine.

Comment: @Karthi1234 Sorry, I'm not familiar with Ruby or the PSK.